# MSSQL - add sql middle IF - ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good morning. I'm a beginner in SQL.

I want to modify the `MS-SQL` procedure below.

I would like to add a branch statement in the middle of the query statement, but it is not as good as I thought.

Thank you!

```
WITH W_TEST AS (
    SELECT T1.ID
        ,T2.NAME 
        ,T1.ADDRESS
        ,T1.NUMBER
        FROM TEST_TBL1 T1
        INNER JOIN TEST_TBL2 T2 ON T1.OBJECTID = T2.OBJECTID 
    WHERE T1.TYPE != 14 

    -- ======= This is the part you want to modify.
    IF (Condition 1)
    BEGIN
        GROUP BY T1.ID
            ,T2.NAME 
            ,T1.ADDRESS
            ,T1.NUMBER
        HAVING (
                (SELECT MAX(NEXT_NUM) AS NEXT_NUMBER
                FROM NUMBER_TBL1
                WHERE GRADE = 3
                ) < MAX(T1.NUMBER)
        )
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Branch statement not including grammar
    END
    -- ======= This is the part you want to modify.

  )
```

Comment: You can't create a non dynamic query using `IF` in this manner.  You will either need dynamic SQL, or else you will have to find a way to write a single query to handle your logic.

Comment: There's something confused here - you're trying to use `T1.NUMBER` both as a `GROUP BY` expression *and* in the `MAX` aggregate. It would probably be *far clearer* if you presented us with some sample data, a short *narrative* of your overall objective and then the *expected results*. ("I want to use `IF` here" isn't the problem - it's your attempt at a solution but you've not told us what the problem is)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate statements or use dynamic T-SQL. Since, you are beginner it will be clear for use use separate statements:

```
 IF (Condition 1)
    BEGIN
        WITH W_TEST AS (
        SELECT T1.ID
            ,T2.NAME 
            ,T1.ADDRESS
            ,T1.NUMBER
            FROM TEST_TBL1 T1
            INNER JOIN TEST_TBL2 T2 ON T1.OBJECTID = T2.OBJECTID 
        WHERE T1.TYPE != 14 
         GROUP BY T1.ID
            ,T2.NAME 
            ,T1.ADDRESS
            ,T1.NUMBER
        HAVING (
                (SELECT MAX(NEXT_NUM) AS NEXT_NUMBER
                FROM NUMBER_TBL1
                WHERE GRADE = 3
                ) < MAX(T1.NUMBER)
        )
        ...
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        WITH W_TEST AS (
        SELECT T1.ID
            ,T2.NAME 
            ,T1.ADDRESS
            ,T1.NUMBER
            FROM TEST_TBL1 T1
            INNER JOIN TEST_TBL2 T2 ON T1.OBJECTID = T2.OBJECTID 
        WHERE T1.TYPE != 14 
        )
        ..
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need prepare your required middle query and then build your final query by concatenating with middle query. you can get some idea from this link:
[Building Dynamic Query](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)